# Csv file being saved in software folder csvhelper c#

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, csvhelper

so I have a program that extracts a csvTable from a csvFile structured like:

```
string Output_Path = Output_Path_value(output_path); 
            string Conversion_Logic = Conversion_Logic_value(conversion_logic); //Conversion_Logic
            var textwriter = Console.Out;
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(textwriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(Output_Path + @"\" + Conversion_Logic + "_" + fileName))
            using (var csv_write = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            using (var reader = new StringReader(sb.ToString()))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
                csv.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = true;
                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvTable_Headers_Map>();
                csv.Read();
                csv.ReadHeader();
                csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = row => row[0].StartsWith("__") || row[0].StartsWith("T");
                var records = csv.GetRecords<CsvTable_Headers>();
                csv_write.WriteRecords(records);
                //csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);// this has to be before or not exist for file to save correctly
            }
```

The purpose of this code is to save the CsvTable to a seperate file, and then save it to the that specified output path. Everything here works, however something happens is that it also saves that file to the Debug folder, when it shouldnt. How should I structure it so that it does not save it there, and only to the output path?

I am also using the open source library, csvHelper.

Comment: What is the value of `output_path`?  What does `Output_Path_value(output_path)` return?  What's the full runtime path that you're using for the `StreamWriter`?

Comment: The value for output _Path is as follows: `@"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\NewFolder"`. And for that, what `Output_Path_value(output_path)` returns is that path